# Ruby on Rails: dataTable results stops at 30 records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

I created a dataTable used for viewing Subjects that I enter. For some reason, even though I can still enter subjects (and they are saved into the database), only 30 records can be shown on the table. I can't find anywhere that explicitly limits the table to 30 line items.

I'm looking for advice on where to look, or reasons why my table would be limited. I'll post code as requested.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT.

So I checked the logs, as you said, and sure enough I see it right there:

```
Started GET "/screening_log" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-25 13:21:58 -0700
Processing by SubjectsController#screening_log as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSubject Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "subjects".* FROM "subjects" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "subjects" 
  Rendered subjects/screening_log.html.erb within layouts/application (14.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21.3ms (Views: 19.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Limit 30. I'm trying to find where the database is called right now. It's not in SubjectsController, which is confusing to me. But I'll keep looking. Thank you for the advice!

EDIT 2.

As a side note, if I type Subject.all in the console, it's limited by 30.

Comment: Can you post the ActiveRecord query that gives you the result, and relevant portion on logs. A good place to start debugging will be log/development.log. There you will be able to see the actual database query being executed. If you can update your question with those, I can try and help.

Comment: Do you have pagination activated? Maybe a `default_scope`?

Comment: I do have pagination activated. I don't have a default_scope though. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Yes, looks like it is a default scope. Can you paste your model code as well.

Comment: I have nothing in the model relating to it. You meant the Subject model right?

Comment: Yes, the Subject model. If you don't have a default scope in your model, then a way to debug is - remove one gem at a time from your Gemfile, and see if it goes away. If it does, try looking at the documentation of that gem.

Comment: How about a project wide search in your editor for "limit(30)" just to make sure it's not somewhere in your project.

Comment: Project wide search returned no results. I also tried turning off each gem, and that didn't yield results either. Could it be the pg gem? I can't really test that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using pagination, then the default value is '30' if you don't set it with `.per_page(num)`

It's part of the `will_paginate` API, see this link for details: [will_paginate API.](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation%22will_paginate%20API%20wiki%22)

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IanEllis happy to help, was there myself not too long ago... :-)